# pandas filter by datetime after grouby

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

After grouping a dataframe by a certain column, I want to select the dates in the first six months of the year preceding the last value of each key of the grouped column.
For example, in this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-01-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-02-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-09-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-10-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-01-01', 'quantity': 2 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-02-01', 'quantity': 2 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-02-11', 'quantity': 2 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-09-01', 'quantity': 2 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-10-01', 'quantity': 2 },
])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df
```

[image]

I would like to select the first 2 lines of `thing 1` and the the first 3 lines of `thing 2`.

I can find the begin and end date for each `id`:

```
df.groupby('id').date.max()-pd.DateOffset(years=1)
df.groupby('id').date.max()-pd.DateOffset(months=6)
```

but I cannot find a way to select the dates in between.

---

My best (and naive) attempt, which is probably wrong in many ways, was the following:

```
df[(df.groupby('id').date>(df.groupby('id').date.max()-pd.DateOffset(years=1))) & (df.groupby('id').date<(df.groupby('id').date.max()-pd.DateOffset(months=6)))]
```

which understandably returns

> TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and SeriesGroupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` and get the highest date on each row. Then we substract 6 months with `pd.DateOffset` and finally compare it to each row with `Series.lt` which stands for `less than`, same as `<`:

```
max_date = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform('max') - pd.DateOffset(months=6)
df[df['date'].lt(max_date)]
# or df[df['date'] < max_date]
```

**Output**

```
        id       date  quantity
0  thing 1 2016-01-01         1
1  thing 1 2016-02-01         1
4  thing 2 2017-01-01         2
5  thing 2 2017-02-01         2
6  thing 2 2017-02-11         2
```

Comment: When I run it I get "Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and Timestamp"...
But it seems the right way!
One caveat is that I  also have to specify a min_date; I assume I can just do `.gt(min_date)`?

Comment: Make sure your columns are all `datetime` type. Yes first make a min_date series. If you need any help, let me know.

Comment: I managed to do it but in two lines of code `df=df[df['date'].lt(max_date)]' and `df=df[df['date'].gt(min_date)]' where `min_date = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform('max') - pd.DateOffset(years=1)`. Is there a one-liner that works? I got a vast zoo of errors trying some variations of `df[(df['date'].lt(max_date)) and (df[df['date'].gt(min_date)])]`

Comment: Pandas uses `&` as logical operator, so do: `df[df['date'].lt(max_date) & df['date'].gt(min_date)]`

Comment: ah! right... but now I get `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: If you didnt use `lt` or `gt`, make sure to use brackets around your conditions, for example: `(df['date'] < max_date)`, maybe read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) for your understanding

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a daft way to do it but...You can add a new column into your df for month based on the existing dates.

```
df['MONTH'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month
```

It will make Jan 1, Feb 2 etc

Then filter off that column for the first six months where | means or

```
df = df.loc[df['MONTH'] == 1]|[df['MONTH'] == 2]|[df['MONTH'] == 3]|[df['MONTH'] == 4]|[df['MONTH'] == 5]|[df['MONTH'] == 6]|
```

Comment: a concise way to do this : `df.loc[df.date.dt.month.between(1,6)]`